# What does "Waiting" mean in the VS debugger parallel tasks?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, parallel-processing, task

```
3   Waiting HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 6904 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
4   Running HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 6880 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
5   Waiting HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 6884 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
6   Waiting HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 6536 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
7   Waiting HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 6992 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
8   Waiting HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 5148 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
9   Waiting HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 7016 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
10  Running HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load   ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 7096 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
11  Waiting HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get ProcessTorrent.AnonymousMethod__6() 6988 (Worker Thread)    1 (torrent.vshost.exe)
```

You can see only 2 tasks are running, does that mean the others in waiting status are waiting for the 2 running tasks to finish or are they waiting for the HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get to complete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be waiting on anything.  It could be another thread, it could be for the OS to do something (such as file/network IO to complete) it could be for a timer, or just to be scheduled after what they're waiting on has finished.

In this case, given the remainder of the line being: `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get`, it would appear they're waiting on network IO.